# Flask flashed messages not showing

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to flash messages in Flask using flash(), but the messages aren't appearing on the page. It isn't in the source code for the page either when looking at it with Dev Tools.

Here is the code that I have in my base.html *It is outside of the blocks*:

```html
        {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
            <p>1</p>
            {% if messages %}
                <p>2</p>
                {% for message, category in messages %}
                    <p>3</p>
                    {% if category == 'success' %}
                        <p>4</p>
                        <div class='message success'>
                            <p>{{ message }}</p>
                        </div>
                    {% elif category == 'error' %}
                        <div class='message error'>
                            <p>{{ message }}</p>
                        </div>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}
```

Python code(shortened to include relevant bits)

```py
@app.route('/suggestion', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def suggestion():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ...
        content = f'Name: {name}\nEmail: {email}\nQuestion: {question}\nAnswer: {answer}\nType: {type}\nTopic: {topic}'

        if sensible == 'Agreed' and accurate == 'Agreed':
            email = Email()
            sent = email.sendEmail(content)

            if sent:
                flash('Suggestion submitted successfully', category='success')
            else:
                flash('Error submitting suggestion. Please try again later',
                      category='error')

        return redirect(url_for('suggest'))
```

Using the `p` tags to see where it's failing, I can tell that the `{% if messages %}` isn't working, but I don't know why.

I'm using `flash('Message', category='success')` to send the messages. I've looked at the Flask documentation and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Please can someone help?

Comment: Can you add python code too?

Comment: Updated with Python code!

Comment: Perhaps the `if/else` conditions within your python file which actually flash the messge, are not being reached within your test request.  This would explain `messages` being `None` by the time the template is rendered?

Comment: I tried putting one after the `if/else`, and the message didn't show up. However, I got 1, 2, 3, 3 at the top of my page which means that it couldn't find the category on the `if/elif` test. They are definitely spelt correctly though.

Comment: Apparently the order of `category` and `message` in the `for` loop actually matters! You need to do `{% for category, message in messages %}` not `{% for message, category in messages %}`. It seems a little weird to me, but it works with that the other way around!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this implementation
**`Routes.py`**

```
@auth.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
            if user is not None and user.confirm_password(form.password.data):
                login_user(user)
                flash("Login successful", "success")
                return redirect(url_for("home.index"))
        flash("Invalid email or password", "error")
    return render_template("auth/login.html", form=form)
```

**`_message.html` template**

```
<div class="flash-message">
  <div class="msg-wrapper">
    {% with messages=get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %} 
     {% if messages %} 
     {% for category,message in messages %}
     <p class="{{category}} message">{{message}}</p>
    {% endfor %} 
   {% endif %} 
 {% endwith %}
  </div>
</div>
```

Looping through the messages and categories in reverse

Comment: Thanks, but I already got it figured out and posted the issue as a comment on the main question.